# How to retrieve JSON key having array of values using YAJL RPGLE

Tags: rpgle, yajl

I am just starting to explore on writing/parsing JSON using [YAJL](https://www.scottklement.com/yajl/) in RPGLE

I am encountering a situation were i need to parse a key with array of values

e.g. {"key":[value1,value2,value2]}

I am seeing examples to parse array of objects i.e. { "key" : [ {"k1":"v1"}, {"k2":"v2"} , {"k3":"v3"} ] }

```
list = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'key');
i = 0;
dow YAJL_ARRAY_LOOP( list: i: node );
  val = YAJL_object_find(node: 'k1');
  value1 = yajl_get_string(val);
enddo;
```

But not for the array of values for single Key. Any idea how we can do this using YAJL in RPGLE.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a matter of removing a line in your example and making a small modification.  You have no need to look for the object in the array loop because you already have the relevant value.

```
list = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'key');
i = 0;
dow YAJL_ARRAY_LOOP( list: i: node );
  value1 = yajl_get_string(node);
enddo;
```

If you are on the latest version of IBM i (7.3 TR4 as of this comment), you should probably look into using the [DATA-INTO](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/zzdatainto.htm#zzdatainto) RPG opcode or if you want it in a relational format, you can use SQL [JSON_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-json-table-trs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I am able to get the values. Our version of IBM i is V7R2, Let me have a look at other options you have suggested. Thanks again.